# Ruby on Rails logic in active record condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm building a site for users to post events they wish to sell tickets for.

I'm writing a query where the conditions are the follow:

- active equals true
- sales_stop is < Time.now

The problem I am having is coming up with a condition which tests whether or not a record's sales_stop time is less than Time.now.

Below is what I have as of now:

```
@events = Event.paginate :page => params[:page],
      :conditions => {:active => true},
      :order => "created_at DESC"
```

In turn, I've been toying around with the sales_stop condition with no luck.

I've been trying something like this:

```
@events = Event.paginate :page => params[:page],
      :conditions => {:active => true, :sales_stop < Time.now},
      :order => "created_at DESC"
```

This of course doesn't work.

Does anyone know how I can set this query up so that I only retrieve records where the sales_stop attribute is less than Time.now?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use the alternate syntax for :conditions, which uses a bind-style:

```
@events = Event.paginate :page => params[:page],
      :conditions => ['active = ? AND sales_stop < ?', true, Time.now],
      :order => "created_at DESC"
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
@events = Event.paginate :page => params[:page],
  :conditions => ['active=? AND sales_stop < ?', true, Time.now],
  :order => "created_at DESC"
```

Just a different syntax.